# sample code for Microsoft Dynamics 365 CRM authentication and then redirect to C# console application

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm

I want to C# console application code for Microsoft authentication, and when I click button redirect to Microsoft login page and after authentication redirect to C# application. Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hey, it'd be useful to know what code you've already tried, or a wider description of the context of your situation and what you're trying to achieve. See [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guide.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest installing [D365DeveloperExtensions](https://github.com/jlattimer/D365DeveloperExtensions) for Visual Studio. This will give you a pre-built template for creating a console application that connects to a Dynamics 365 environment.

Alternatively below is sample code for login options with either a credential prompt (Microsoft login page) or without. Code taken from [this blog](https://jlattimer.blogspot.com/2015/11/crm-web-api-using-c.html).

```cs
//Azure Application Client ID
private const string _clientId = "00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
// Azure Application REPLY URL - can be anything here but it must be registered ahead of time
private const string _redirectUrl = "http://localhost/CrmWebApi";
//CRM URL
private const string _serviceUrl = "https://org.crm.dynamics.com";
//O365 credentials for authentication w/o login prompt
private const string _username = "administrator@org.onmicrosoft.com";
private const string _password = "password";
//Azure Directory OAUTH 2.0 AUTHORIZATION ENDPOINT
private const string _authority = 
 "https://login.microsoftonline.com/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000";
private static AuthenticationResult _authResult;
AuthenticationContext authContext =
    new AuthenticationContext(_authority, false);
//Prompt for credentials
//_authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(
//    _serviceUrl, _clientId, new Uri(_redirectUrl));

//No prompt for credentials
UserCredential credentials = new UserCredential(_username, _password);
_authResult = authContext.AcquireToken(
    _serviceUrl, _clientId, credentials);

var token = _authResult.AccessToken;
```